# How to create a view in MySQL without listing all column names

Tags: mysql

I am bit lazy to write all the column names from all the tables when joining more tables while creating a view. Struggling with a problem of duplicity in column names (I use column name 'id' in all tables).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW new_table AS 
SELECT * FROM a_table a 
LEFT JOIN b_table b ON a.specific1_id = b.id 
LEFT JOIN c_table c ON a.specific2_id = c.id
WHERE 1;
```

I get an error - `#1060 - Duplicate column name 'id'`

Solution is write all the column names instead of * .... but its too much work, right?

Thanks for hints,
Zdenka

Comment: `Select a.*, b.field1, b.field2... c.field1, c.field2...`  Or, you could use system tables to select all the columns for the tables in your query and copy/paste the results to your select aliasing the duplicates or eliminating them.`SELECT  table_name, GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME IN ('b_table','a_table','c_table')  GROUP BY table_name;`  Put another way you query system to get all the columns for your tables so you don't have to type them out, but you'd still have to alias or remove duplicates (ids)

Comment: So what benefit do you really get by not naming the column names? When you do so you will be able to revisit the query or view at a future date and know exactly what is being specified for that query. You've already answered your question of course, you want the easy way out.

Comment: Great it works, thanks a lot.

Comment: And yes I am lazy to write it. I am now preparing some solution but its more like "try and see" approach - when I will have some final version I will rather write all the columns one by one to have it readable for future. Thanks guys for hints!